# Django's STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage" creates hashed static file names, but doesn't read them

Tags: python, django, md5

When I run `collectstatic` everything is as it should be. The appointed `STATIC_ROOT` directory has all the collected files with original and hashed filenames.

When I run the server, however, Django throws me an `500 server error` and doesn't load any of the files.

When I change `STATICFILES_STORAGE` to  `"django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage"` instead of `"django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage"`, everything works fine and the static files with their original filenames are served.

Has anyone a clue? Do I need to import `"django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage"` somwwhere. I read the whole documentation, but nothing...

Comment: Can you add the full traceback from the error to your question

Comment: I get this error in the terminal `[07/Aug/2022 09:27:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145` and the html templates don't load at all when using `"django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage"`.